# Not sure how to instantiate MapView iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working on making an app for iPhone that uses a map. I had the app working through storyboards, but I decided to switch to writing the app programmatically so that I could actually feel like I was learning the code I'm writing. However, I now can't run my app, I'm erroring out with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."

My ViewController looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class GoOut: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
let APP_ID = "5738E396-74BB-E1BD-FF13-C6916832AA00"
let SECRET_KEY = "BA71250D-582B-0E65-FF9A-35CAD17AF800"
let VERSION_NUM = "v1"

var pin_array: [[Double]] = []

var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()
var pressed = false
var date: NSDate? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let longPressRecogniser = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")

    longPressRecogniser.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecogniser)

    mapView.delegate = self

    let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 42.447918, longitude: -76.487844)

    centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
    backendless.initApp(APP_ID, secret:SECRET_KEY, version:VERSION_NUM)
    backendless.hostURL = "http://api.backendless.com"

    getMapPins()
    var pin_number = 0

    for element in pin_array {
        let pin = Pin(title: String(pin_number),
            coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: element[0], longitude: element[1]))

        mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
        pin_number++

    }
}
```

And I have a ViewController extension for this class that looks like:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

extension GoOut: MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? Pin {
        let identifier = "pin"
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
            as? MKPinAnnotationView { // 2
                dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = false
            view.animatesDrop = true
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

My error is coming in when I try to modify mapView in the view controller. Does anyone have any suggestions?

edit: I added

```
mapView = MKMapView()
```

to my view controller, which allows the app to run, but no map is showing up.

Comment: You say you had it working in storyboards and now you are trying to create it in code. You still have the IBOutlet though. Where are you creating your mapView?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post, I added a line that I think instantiates the mapView!

Comment: You aren't using storyboards so just creating a mapView instance isn't going to be enough. You actually need to size it (probably best using auto layout) and adding it to your view as a subview.

Comment: So view.addSubview(mapView)?

Comment: You still need to set it's size and position.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much